# Background Video Filter Hides Overlaying Div

Tags: css, filter, webkit, html5-video

When adding any filter to our background video, the div overlay moves behind the video (becoming hidden). Here is a fiddle showing the background video with the text overlay:
https://jsfiddle.net/dyrepk2x/2/

Add the following webkit-filter to the video css as indicated here:

```
video {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
-webkit-filter: brightness(.5); /* add these filters */
filter: brightness(.5); /* this line works too */
}
```

The video overlay disappears behind the video. How can I have a filter and keep the overlay on top of the video?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a z-index of anything higher than 1

```
z-index: 5;
```

Works for me here:
https://jsfiddle.net/dyrepk2x/3/

Comment: Epic fail, I could've sworn I tried that. Thank you Josh Sanger